# Problem with comma in insert statement

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

Am facing problem while inserting data into sqlserver using query in c# as

```
Insert into table1(sid,sname) values(1,'ram,rahim,robert')
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You've only told us half of what you need to.

Comment: error message is string or binary data would be truncated

Comment: Sounds like your field 'sname' is too small. What datatype (and which length) does sname has?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using quotes around the variable in the command string? Try using the command without quotes.

```
command.text=string.Format("insert into table(sid,sname) values(1,@data)");
```

String or binary data would be truncated is an error indicating that you are trying to store a string that is longer than the field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

use like

```
insert into table1(sid,sname,column3,column4) values(1,'ram','rahim','robert')
```

But you have to add four columns.Now you have only two sid and sname. Add another two columns.

Comment: but i have only two columns in my table,i need to enter , in my sname column

Comment: then pass two values like values(1,'ramrahimjohn');

Comment: but i need to insert comma(,) in the value

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @str varchar(200)
set @str = 'ram,rahim,robert';
Insert into table1(sid,sname) values(1,@str )
```

Comment: am using this query in c# as follows command.text=string.Format("insert into table(sid,sname) values(1,"@data")); cmd.parameters.add("@data",SqlDbType.varchar); cmd.parameters["@data"].value="ram,robert,rahim"; cmd.executenonquery()

Comment: it is giving string or binary data would be truncated

Comment: what is your size of column "sname"